# Contact Form that is not a .php extension

Tags: html

recently i have been trying to so make a contact form work and i finally did after hours of struggle.
http://trulyamped.com/democon/contact2.php 
This contact form works perfectly and the email gets sent to my account.
The only thing i wanted to know was how do i make the contact form work in an .html file. I do not want it to be in a .php file. I already tried to save the file as an .html file but it did not work. Please let me know. 
so pretty much i want it to be contact2.html and still be able to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it did not work". What exactly happened?

Comment: Is there a reason you dony want php extensions? You need it to send emails don't you

Comment: I am a complete noob when it comes to emailing/forms/ajax and php. I just don't like the fact that it is a php file. id prefer it to be an .html file but i am lost when it comes to this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why does it matter?

But assuming for a moment that it does matter, you probably have a couple of options.  They depend on where your code resides and what it currently does.  If the page has PHP code that needs to execute server-side then it needs to be processed by the PHP interpreter server-side.  To do that with an HTML file you'd need to configure the server to treat `.html` files just like `.php` files for server-side processing.  This isn't ideal, though.  HTML by itself doesn't need to be run through the PHP interpreter.  So it's best to keep the PHP and HTML files separate.

Another option could simply be to separate the client-side HTML form and the server-side PHP code into two separate files.  Something like `contact.html` and `contactProcessor.php`.  In the HTML file you'd just post to the PHP file in the form.  Something like this:

```
<form action="contactProcessor.php" method="post">
```

This would cause the form to post the data to the PHP file.  Then the PHP file can process the data, do whatever you're currently doing server-side, and redirect the user to another HTML file as a response.  So at no point would the user be "viewing" a PHP file.  There's just be one used to handle the form post.

Again, I can't imagine why it matters though.

Comment: Would it be better for the file to be an .php file. I just feel that all of my pages are .html and then i have one page for contact that is a .php file. Just makes it feel unbalanced

Comment: @TeoAlmonte: It might unbalance the feng shui of the website, but otherwise doesn't make a difference.  The file extension doesn't really matter when it comes to a URL, it's only a matter of convention for particular setups that it maps directly to a "file" on the server.  But in any event, it seems perfectly reasonable that the one page which has server-side functionality would have a `.php` extension.

Comment: I also keep getting error messages and this file permissions thing is killing me. I just want the .php file externally. this is so much work....haha

Comment: yeah i keep getting 500 internal server error... this is why i need html lmao

Comment: @TeoAlmonte: A 500 error means something failed in the server-side code.  Check the PHP logs.  Renaming the file to HTML won't fix the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a 2nd page that only has the email processing logic, let's call that `email.php` you could then update your form to post to `email.php` and change this page to be `contact2.html` as long as it posts to a `.php` file it will work.

```
<form id="contact-us" action="email.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bet is to use AJAX for the main form but will still need a server side script page to handle the mail sending. As far as I know, it's not possible to send mails from the client side.

So

1. Have the PHP page that actually sends the mail in a separate script file
2. Create your form in HTML and use AJAX to call the mail sending script from within your HTML page.

This way you can have your page in html and do the mail sending at the background.

Regarding saving your page with .html extension, of course it wouldn't work. Because your page contains PHP which is server-side and needs a web server to run, while html can be run on any simple browser on any device.